# Make for...of to skip from looping the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, for-of-loop

In case that there is a bi-dimensional array which is iterated using `for...of`, how is the best way to skip the last element?

For example, having an array `arr`, the normal approach would be:

`for(const subArray of arr) { ... }`

to skip the last element it could be used before the loop: `arr.slice(0, -1);` which works fine but it removes that data which should be avoided.

Is there a way to make it skip the last element without losing data?

Comment: You can keep an index and check if you're on the last element or not

Comment: Just use a plain old `for` loop

Comment: Or just check each time `if (subArray === arr[arr.length - 1]) { /* last element */ }`

Comment: I think `slice` would be the correct approach.  It returns a shallow copy, so does not affect the original array:  `for(const subArray of arr.slice(0, -1)) { ... }`

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 2; i++) {
      subArray = arr[i];}

Comment: The "correct" approach is to use a plain old `for` loop just as @Andreas recommended. Why force-use a `for..of` loop? Because it's new and "edgy"?

Comment: @nicholas because its more expressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) does not change the array, but returns a new array (unlike [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), which does mutate the array), therefore it is safe to use:

```
for (const subArray of arr.slice(0, -1)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a generator:

```
function* skipLast(array, numOfEntries = 1) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length - numOfEntries; i++)
     yield array[i];
}
```

Usable as:

```
for(const entry of skipLast(array))
```